# Display Category Image/Description based on Category Id in url Query String

Tags: categories, supersearch, ee2.11

I'm working on an EE2 site (yes I know it's old) and we have a super search search results page that displays results from one particular category based on the url.

What I need to do is get the category id from the url which looks like this:

h`ttps://domain.com/articles/results/search&keywords=&category=COVID-19&catId=799/`

Once I have that I can display the category info. Is there a way to do this?

Have tried mo variables but this `-- {get:catId} --` outputs `-- --` so I can't work with that.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by adding a `?` just before `catId=799` and then mo variables worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your working solution is not correct.

To avoid confusion for anyone finding this I'm adding this additional answer.

The [URI standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax) says that you should start a query element of a URI with the `?` symbol.  Subsequently you can separate multiple elements of your query using one of several delimiters, `&` and `;` both are common and work.

So to be correct your URL should have the format:

`https://domain.com/articles/results/search?keywords=&category=COVID-19&catId=799/`

I'm not sure why putting the `?` half-way through the variables works at all, but presumably mo'variables is scanning the URL for the ? and turning what follows into variables.  I'm guessing with your solution you cannot retrieve the value for `category` or `keywords`.

Anyhow, HTH...